# Maintenance of python packages (<=3.7) with numpy dependency considering its recent vulnerability

Tags: python, numpy, security, google-colaboratory, versioning

I maintain a [package](https://github.com/MaaniBeigy/pycvcqv) that requires `numpy`. Recently, a vulnerability has been [reported](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/19038), which is resolved in `numpy` versions higher than 1.22.0. However, I cannot use these safe versions of `numpy` for python versions <=3.7, because numpy 1.22.2 requires Python >=3.8. And, since python 3.7 is the default for services like google [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sU38Fi5fEFN2YQbDKxBLKsYVoxFVEvwy?usp=sharing), I prefer not to deprecate my package for python version 3.7.

Are there any solutions for maintaining python packages with numpy dependencies in python 3.7 without compromising security?

Comment: Are you sure that's an issue you should be worrying about?  I haven't seen an discussion of that issue on SO.

Comment: The fix is only 12 days old!  While I don't fully follow the issue, but comments repeatedly say it only applies in memory error cases.  In other words, when you create arrays that are too large.  And that's most likely to occur in during development on your own machine.  Let others grapple with this for a while before worrying about it yourself.

Comment: The severity of the issue is not negligible, however, regardless of its importance, my CI pipeline includes safety checks (https://github.com/pyupio/safety-db), which will not pass if I don't use the latest release of numpy. I can manually ignore it (--ignore), but it's not a good practice is it?